# indexedDB - moving indexed database

Tags: local-storage, indexeddb

I'm in the evaluation phase of migrating an application from WebSQL to indexedDB.  For support reason with WebSQL I have found it helpful to get a copy of the users WebSQL database and move it onto my machine.  Can I do this with IndexedDB?  If so where is this file?  Also is the best tool to view and edit this the Chrome's debugger tool.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably accomplish this with a simple javascript file that opens a connection to both websql and indexeddb and then reads information from websql and inserts it into indexeddb. You will need to make some important design decisions because indexeddb stores data in a very different manner. You might consider some of the easily-google-able libraries that can access both websql and indexeddb to help you with the script.

You probably would not want to copy the db onto your machine. You can do this entirely within the user's client using a script.

While you might be able to peek into chrome's internals and examine its internal storage mechanisms to find data files to transfer, I would advise against it. There is generally no "file" as you call it that you can copy.

There are many tools for inspecting indexeddb. You can write simple scripts, or you can use chrome's, firefox's, or ie's developer tools to explore the contents of a database. I enjoy using Chrome, but I would not go so far as to say it is categorically the best one.

Comment: The reason I’m looking this migration is because the W3C is no longer behind WebSQL and I’m concerned that one day the browser won’t support it.  So I don’t think I can use script to move it, I’ll have to re-write and remove WebSQL.  Since not all browser support it yet, I’ll guess I’ll have to use the Polyfill shim that does use WebSQL, but this will be short term until there is better browser adoption.  And once I get the browser support that I need I can remove Pollyfill.  Am I understanding correct?

Comment: Oh, and bummer about not having a file to copy with IndexedDB.  For trouble shooting issues, it’s been great to have just one file to copy with WebSQL.  Not having this will complicate troubleshooting production issues.